# Why does VisualStudio Code not find R client

Tags: r, linux, visual-studio-code, manjaro

I am having a weird issue.
I am trying to use R in VisualStudio Code on a Manjaro KDE laptop.
When coding i get the error;

"Cannot find R client at /usr/bin/R. Please check r.rterm setting."

I have launched R on its own in the terminal and it is working fine.

The first thing i tried was adding a path to rpath and rterm, but that has not worked so far. I have tried many other possible places for the R file in the settings, but nothing is working. I get the same error every time.
All help is appreciated.

Comment: Solved it by using OSS Code instead of VSCode flatpak

Comment: Glad to hear you solved it but ideally it would work in VS Code too! That error should occur only when the specified path doesn't exist. Was running `/usr/bin/R` in the terminal starting R successfully?